# Contagem regressiva com minutos e segundos com Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

Como faço para obter uma contagem regressiva com jquery mas **apenas em minutos e segundo -> 04:00 03:59 03:58...** com opção de parar, reiniciar e aumentar e diminuir o tempo alguem poderia me dar um exemplo?

codigo:

```
    var tempo = $("#tempo").text("05:00");
tempo = new Number();
// Tempo em segundos
tempo = 300;
function startCountdown() {
// Se o tempo não for zerado
    if ((tempo - 0) >= 0) {
        // Pega a parte inteira dos minutos
        var min = parseInt(tempo / 60);
        // Calcula os segundos restantes
        var seg = tempo % 60;
        // Formata o número menor que dez, ex: 08, 07, ...
        if (min < 10) {
            min = "0" + min;
            min = min.substr(0, 2);
        }
        if (seg <= 9) {
            seg = "0" + seg;
        }

        // Cria a variável para formatar no estilo hora/cronômetro
        horaImprimivel = min + ':' + seg;


        //JQuery pra setar o valor
        $("#tempo").html(horaImprimivel);

        // Define que a função será executada novamente em 1000ms = 1 segundo
        setTimeout('startCountdown()', 1000);

        // diminui o tempo
        tempo--;


    } else {

    }

}
```

o código conta regressivamente porem como faço para pausar e reiniciar?

Comment: Você sabe JavaScript? O que já tentou fazer?

Comment: Tentei usar o countdown com jquery mas n consegui usar sem data pela documentação do plugin uma vez que lá só tem exemplos a contar partindo pra uma data específica.

Comment: É algo que não é difícil de fazer mesmo com JS puro

Comment: Novamente a pergunta: você sabe JavaScript? Não tente usar jQuery sem saber JavaScript.

Comment: Sei mt pouco de JavaScript, conheço um pouco de jquery

Comment: Comece com Javascript como o Anderson indicou. Vai precisar de usar pelo menos [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval), [`clearInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/clearInterval). Depois ir manipulando os minutos e segundos manualmente

Comment: Um ajuda: https://jsfiddle.net/44d1h9xw/

Comment: editei minha pergunta com meu código de contagem regressiva que ja está funcionando preciso agora pausar e reiniciar.